# The smallest matching expression on the left?

Tags: regex, math, emacs, latex, libreoffice

Here's what I have:

```
{a} {b} over {c} {d}
{a} {{b} over {c}} {d}
```

(I have some text, and it has such expressions) And I want to convert both to:

```
{a} \frac{b}{c} {d}
```

Here's my best bet:

```
(goto-char (point-min))
(while (search-forward-regexp "{+?\\(.+?\\)} +over +{\\(.+?\\)}+?" nil t) 
  (replace-match (concat "\\\\" "frac{\\1}{\\2}") t nil))
```

But it doesn't work. I get:

```
\frac{a} {b}{c} {d}
\frac{a} {{b}{c}} {d}
```

respectively.

The problem is -- my regexp captures as much as possible on the left. While I need it to capture as little as possible.

**Edit**:

The accepted answer doesn't work for more complex cases (which I also need):

```
{d^{2} q} over {d t^{2} }
{{d^{2} q} over {d t^{2} }}
```

(because of nesting)

Here's a working version of parser (the interesting part of the code start from `while`):

```
(defun over2frac ()
  (interactive)
  (let (start end
        (case-fold-search nil)
        lStart lEnd lStr
        rStart rEnd rStr)
    (if (use-region-p)
        (progn (setq start (region-beginning)) ;; then
               (setq end (region-end)))
      (progn (setq start (line-beginning-position)) ;; else
             (setq end (line-end-position))))
    (save-restriction 
      (narrow-to-region start end)
      (goto-char (point-min))

      (while (search-forward-regexp "{\\(.+\\)}\s*over\s*{\\(.+?\\)}" nil t) 

        ;; r:
        (goto-char (match-beginning 2))
        (backward-char 1)
        (setq rStart (point))
        (forward-sexp)
        (setq rEnd (point))
        (setq rStr (buffer-substring-no-properties rStart rEnd))

        ;; l:
        (goto-char (match-end 1))
        (forward-char)
        (setq lEnd (point))
        (backward-sexp)
        (setq lStart (point))
        (setq lStr (buffer-substring-no-properties lStart lEnd))

        (delete-region lStart rEnd)
        (insert "\\" "frac" lStr rStr)
        ))))
```

Since it uses `forward-sexp` and `backward-sexp` -- and doesn't define `syntax-table` -- it only works in appropriate modes (such as `rst-mode` and `text-mode` -- but not `emacs-lisp-mode`. For the above complex examples it gives:

```
\frac{d^{2} q}{d t^{2} }
{\frac{d^{2} q}{d t^{2} }}
```

**Edit 2**:

```
(defun backslash-func--args-on-both-sides (Find Replace)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (while (search-forward-regexp (concat "\\([^{]+\\)}\s*" Find "\s*{\\([^}]+\\)") nil t) 

    ;; r:
    (goto-char (match-beginning 2))
    (backward-char 1)
    (setq rStart (point))
    (forward-sexp)
    (setq rEnd (point))
    (setq rStr (buffer-substring-no-properties rStart rEnd))

    ;; l:
    (goto-char (match-end 1))
    (forward-char)
    (setq lEnd (point))
    (backward-sexp)
    (setq lStart (point))
    (setq lStr (buffer-substring-no-properties lStart lEnd))

    ;; s:
    (goto-char lStart)
    (if (looking-back "{") 
        (setq lStart (1- (point))))

    (goto-char rEnd)
    (if (looking-at "}")
        (setq rEnd (1+ (point))))

    (delete-region lStart rEnd)
    (insert "\\" Replace lStr rStr))

  (goto-char (point-min))
  (while (search-forward-regexp (concat "\\([0-9a-zA-Z_^]+\\)\s*" Find "\s*\\([0-9a-zA-Z_^]+\\)") nil t) (replace-match (concat "\\\\" Replace "{\\1}{\\2}") t nil))
  )
```

This converts both things:

```
{d^{2} q} over {d t^{2} }
{{d^{2} q} over {d t^{2} }}
```

to

```
\frac{d^{2} q}{d t^{2} }
```

I don't use `let` here because all the vars are local already -- and the defun itself is in the other defun. [Full code](https://github.com/bk322/bk-dotfiles/blob/master/.emacs.d/site-lisp/bk/bk_lomath-tex.el).

Comment: Surely it would have been easier to just write two regexps, because one would only require a slight modification from the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this expression: http://regex101.com/r/kY8jY5

`/{+([^{}]+)}\s*over\s*{([^{}]+)}+/g`

The expression should be compatible with emacs.

Replace with:

`\frac{\1}{\2}`

Note: I am unsure if you use `\1` or `$1` in emacs.

Comment: In emacs it is: `(while (search-forward-regexp "{+\\([^{}]+\\)}\s*over\s*{\\([^{}]+\\)}+" nil t) (replace-match (concat "\\\\" "frac{\\1}{\\2}") t nil))`. It's all my bad habit of using `{(.+?)}` instead of `([^{}]+)`.

Answer (score 0):

By adding a greedy `*` at the start of the regexp, and putting it first in the replacement:

```
(goto-char (point-min))
(while (search-forward-regexp "\\(.*\\){+?\\(.+?\\)} +over +{\\(.+?\\)}+?" nil t) 
  (replace-match (concat "\\1\\\\" "frac{\\2}{\\3}") t nil))
```

I got it to produce this:

```
{a} \frac{b}{c} {d}
{a} {\frac{b}{c}} {d}
```

I'm not sure if there's any way to get rid of the extra surrounding `{}`...

Comment: Anyway -- I like the idea of capturing as much as possible on the left.